# How to limit the length of a line on the plot showing the linear regression?

Tags: python, plot, trendline

I am trying to create a graph out of Excel data (2 columns, one for axis `x`, and other for axis `y`), and to show median, mean, and trend line (linear regression).

The problem is with the last component. Median and mean are shown as lines extending from the highest dot until the lowest dot on the scatter plot, however, trendline's length is absolutely random.

Depending on the 2nd column values, sometimes it is short and almost horizontal, but for one set of data it started somewhere in the middle of a plot, and went down below the lowest dot on the graph extending visually the plot and it looks bad.

My question is: How to limit the length of a line on the plot showing the linear regression?

Here is a screenshot of before and after:

[image]

And after adding: np.clip

[image]

I have nicely cut the lower part of the line, but instead of totally limit it below a certain point, I just have limited it's y-values, and it turned into horizontal line at this y-value. This was done simply by limiting value of a function showing y-values of the linear regression trend line, but I don't know how to do it for x values as well.

```
colors = np.where(x<reasonablemin,'k',np.where(x>reasonablemax,'k','y'))
plt.title(plottitle)
ax = plt.axes()
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
ax.scatter(x, y, c=colors) 
finalx = [x for x in x if ((x < reasonablemax) & (x > reasonablemin))]
mask = (x[1:-1] > reasonablemax)
x[1:-1][mask] = np.nan
mask = (x[1:-1] < reasonablemin)
x[1:-1][mask] = np.nan
clearedagain = cleared.dropna()
print(clearedagain)
x = cleared[parameter]
y = cleared['Depth']
xcleared = clearedagain[parameter]
ycleared = clearedagain['Depth']
x = x.values.reshape(len(x), 1)
y = y.values.reshape(len(y), 1)
xcleared = xcleared.values.reshape(len(xcleared), 1)
ycleared = ycleared.values.reshape(len(ycleared), 1)
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(xcleared, ycleared)
x_linearregression = np.linspace(0, reasonablemax)
y_linearregression = model.predict(x_linearregression[:, np.newaxis])
print(y_linearregression)
minimum = min(ycleared)
maximum = max(ycleared)
np.clip(y_linearregression, minimum, maximum, out=y_linearregression)
print(y_linearregression)
linear_regression_line = ax.plot(x_linearregression, y_linearregression, 
label='Trendline', linestyle='dotted')
plt.ylim(max(ycleared)+1,min(ycleared-1))
ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
ax.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

Just to cut that line at the level of the lowest dot. And also the highest if the data set was the other way around.